# How to set more than one html table in an aspx page in different alignments?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, html-table

I am having 5 table which I need to show in one page.

For that I have to show 2 tables in one row and other 3 in second row.

Is it possible to do this in C#? Or is there any other way to do fulfill requirement of getting so many input form user and not show so many tables in page and make it ugly

Comment: could you clarify your question? because there are tables first, then many input form, how they are related?

Comment: Put them into a table,so first row two tables, second row three tables, as per your need set colspan as 2 for any of the cell in the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' not quite sure about what you mean. You can put these tables into another table as their container. Are your tables look like as belows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
           <table id="table1" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
           <table id="table2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
           <table id="table3" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
           <table id="table4" />
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
           <table id="table5" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my tables having different height.in that case how to set for two tables starting from the same top? i am trying to use style->margin but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can. Just use HTML to add it onto your aspx page like you would on a normal html page.

Open your ASPX page in Visual Studio, then down the bottom left of the screen you'll see 'source', click on that and add the tables in like a normal html page. You may need to add some CSS to the tables to make them stay on the one line.